# Empty reply from server When accessing PHP page from C#

Tags: c#, php

> ```
> Empty reply from server
> ```

When and why this error comes ? I try to access PHP page from my C# code then it gives me this error. I think that it is not code fault anyhow if someone figure it out then it will be good. I have exhaustivel search it but no success my code is simple.

```
 string dataGetURL = "http://localhost/HighScore/GetScore.php";
    WWW getData = new WWW(dataGetURL);
    yield return getData;
    if (getData.error != null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("There was an error getting the high score: " + getData.error);
    }
    else {
        print(getData.text);
    }
```

dataGetURL is perfectly working when i directly put it into my browser but i dont know why it is not working with C# Unity [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future users, It just worked by changing the localhost into my Computer IP.

```
string dataGetURL = "http://your IP Address/HighScore/GetScore.php";
```